# how to give admin relief of relogin admin panel after every 5 10 minute of idle state?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0

I am implementing admin panel using `c#` in `visual studio 2008`

I have not used any extra ordinary authentication.Just checked user name and password of admin from `appsettings` in `web config`

When admin stays ideal for 5 to 10 minutes it again asks for login.

I am doing just this on `login` `button click`

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((txtUser.Text == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"]) && 
        (txtPassword.Text == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]))
    {
        this.Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
        base.Response.Redirect("~/admin/abcdefg.aspx");
    }
}
```

how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase  Sessiontimeout for more time where username and passwords pamtches admin's.this may avoid to login every 5 to 10 mins